# Why does Load Average of my Linux hosting server keeps swinging from 6 to 33?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, php, php-fpm

Lately, I've noticed a weird behaviour on my production server of a moderately high traffic WordPress website. (concurrent realtime traffic around ~1500)

The server is capable:

```
DigitalOcean 48GB Memory
16 Core Processor
480GB SSD Disk
```

The issue is that the Load Average (LA) stays at 6 for approx 30 mins, then rises steadily to around 33 and then stays at 33 for approx 30 mins. Then goes back to 6 (normal) and it continues endlessly.

When the LA is 20+, the site becomes horribly slow to open. So obviously, my visitors are getting frustrated and leaving the site because it's taking forever to open. And I'm losing visitors due to that. :(

Tweaked a few nginx, php-frm, sysctl.conf, mysql (my.cnf) settings, but nothing seems to be working.

**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 16;
worker_rlimit_nofile 100000;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 4096;
        multi_accept on;
}
```

But my `ulimit -n` returns only `1024`

**php.ini**

```
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
max_input_vars = 5000
memory_limit = 128M
post_max_size = 100M
default_socket_timeout = 60
pdo_mysql.cache_size = 2000
```

**www.conf**

```
listen = 127.0.0.1:9090
listen.backlog = 65536
pm = static
pm.max_children = 500
pm.start_servers = 60
pm.min_spare_servers = 45
pm.max_spare_servers = 75
pm.max_requests = 5000
request_terminate_timeout = 300
```

**sysctl.conf**

```
fs.file-max = 2097152

# Do less swapping
vm.swappiness = 10
vm.dirty_ratio = 60
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 2

# Decrease the time default value for tcp_fin_timeout connection
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 15

# Decrease the time default value for connections to keep alive
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 300
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 5
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 15

### TUNING NETWORK PERFORMANCE ###

# Default Socket Receive Buffer
net.core.rmem_default = 31457280

# Maximum Socket Receive Buffer
net.core.rmem_max = 12582912

# Default Socket Send Buffer
net.core.wmem_default = 31457280

# Maximum Socket Send Buffer
net.core.wmem_max = 12582912

# Increase number of incoming connections
net.core.somaxconn = 65536
# Increase number of incoming connections backlog
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 65536

# Increase the maximum amount of option memory buffers
net.core.optmem_max = 25165824

# Increase the maximum total buffer-space allocatable
# This is measured in units of pages (4096 bytes)
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 65536 131072 262144
net.ipv4.udp_mem = 65536 131072 262144

# Increase the read-buffer space allocatable
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 8192 87380 16777216
net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min = 16384

# Increase the write-buffer-space allocatable
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 8192 65536 16777216
net.ipv4.udp_wmem_min = 16384

# Increase the tcp-time-wait buckets pool size to prevent simple DOS attacks
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 1440000
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
```

**my.cnf**

```
    #
    # * Fine Tuning
    #
    max_connections         = 1000
    connect_timeout         = 5
    wait_timeout            = 600
    max_allowed_packet      = 16M
    thread_cache_size       = 128
    sort_buffer_size        = 4M
    bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M
    tmp_table_size          = 32M
    max_heap_table_size     = 32M
query_cache_limit               = 128K
query_cache_size                = 64M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024M
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 8M
innodb_file_per_table   = 1
innodb_open_files       = 400
innodb_io_capacity      = 400
innodb_flush_method     = O_DIRECT
```

Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

EDIT

TOP screenshot when Load Average is 30+
[image]

Comment: Open top or htop and post the results when you experiencing high load. Does your account at Digital Ocean have any system monitoring tools/graphs? You are likely running out of either memory or cpu. The first step is figuring out which one, and the second is figuring out why.

Answer (score 1):

Per your screenshot showing 599% CPU in `mysqld`, the database is the source of your problems.

I would put all the files you 'tweaked' back to their default settings. Chances are you changed stuff after random googling when you didn't know what the actual problem was.

After that, you should run [MySQL Tuner](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl) to get suggestions of where you should adjust your `my.cnf` settings (innodb cache for example is likely undersized). After that, you will also want to check your slow query log.

After making these changes, if you are still having issues, create a new question detailing your database issues (assuming `myslqd` is still a source of problems).

Comment: Thank you so much, Bert. Doing exactly that now.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check correlation between CPU load, network connection count and outgoing traffic?

It will also be good to analyze I/O stats. You may need to increase `worker_process` count is I/O gets overwhelmed.

Another good practice will be to run `chkrootkit` just to be sure, and take a look at `auth.log` for any unusual activity.

I hope you have wordpress [REST API](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/rest-api-exposed-user-data-for-all-users/) secured.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. I'm new to server backend, so can you kindly elaborate on how to check the correlation.

People suggest to keep the `worker_process` to the number of cores, so I kept it that way. Wouldn't increasing it choke the server?

Will check `chkrootkit` and WP REST API now.

Comment: Run `dstat` and see what causes bottleneck. Concerning mysql Bert has excellent point.